# notification sound in build version in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I created one notification using **kendo**,when notification araises i kept `system.media.systemsounds.hand.play()`,

it is working fine while my project is running,when i publish my project and run in build version notification sounds are not coming?

what should i do?

```
        public JsonResult DemoNotification()
        {
          List<DemoNotification> res = new List<DemoNotification>();
          DataTable dt = Functions.GetTbl(cmd);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
             {
               for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++){
                    DemoNotification obj = new DemoNotification();
                    obj.CompanyName = dt.Rows[i]["CompanyName"].ToString();
                    obj.DemoDate =Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]"DemoDate"]);
                    res.Add(obj);
                    System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
                }

            }
            return Json(res);
        }
     function load() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: root("CRM/DemoNotification"),
                    type: "POST",

                }).done(function (data) {
                    for (var i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
                        notification.ShowDemoSuccess("Demo for <b>" + data[i - 1].CompanyName.toString() + "</b> on", Date(data[i - 1].DemoDate));
                    }


                });
            }
```